# Final element with '.' does not write correctly to file

Tags: r, regex, file-io, gsub

I have a long vector of decimal values:

```
spect <- c(0.0005862, 0.0005983, 0.0006225, 0.0006637, 0.0006622, 0.0006197, 0.0005990, 0.0005983, 0.0006247, 0.0006707, 0.0006641)
```

Using gsub, I try to take 5 elements each time and write to a row in a file (thx to user akrun)

```
cat(gsub("\\s*(([0-9.]+\\s+){1,4}\\d+)", "\\1\n",
         paste(unlist(spect), collapse="      ")), '\n', file = "file.txt")
```

But the output looks like this:

```
0.0005862      0.0005983      0.0006225      0.0006637      0
.0006622      0.0006197      0.000599      0.0005983      0
.0006247      0.0006707      0
.0006641
```

What causes the final element to not be written correctly and start a new line before the '.'?

The result should look like this:

```
0.0005862      0.0005983      0.0006225      0.0006637      0.0006622 
0.0006197      0.000599      0.0005983      0.0006247      0.0006707 
0.0006641
```

Comment: What a strange way of approaching this. I'd do `length(spect) <- (length(spect) %/% 5 + 1) * 5; spect[is.na(spect)] <- ""; DF <- data.frame(matrix(spect, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE))` and then use `write.table` with appropriate settings. Wrap in a function if you don't want to modify the input vector.

Comment: Regular expressions describe *text* on the *character level*. They are wholly unsuited to manipulate non-textual data based on some non-textual meaning. I’d generally use a combination of `split` and `cut` here, but in this particular case it’s a lot more convoluted than Ronak’s elegant answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm just starting to work more with R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a vector input you don't need regex to do this. Try :

```
cat(paste0(tapply(spect, ceiling(seq_along(spect)/5), 
    paste0, collapse = '     '), collapse = '\n'), file = "file.txt")
```

Comment: Very slight variation: `writeLines(paste(tapply(spect, (seq_along(spect) - 1L) %/% 5L, paste, collapse = '\t'), collapse = '\n'))` (uses a more natural index numbering which avoids `ceiling`).